# Excel Macro throws error if the file exceeds certain number of rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a excel macro vba script to create text files for each customer code from a file that has total of 32000 rows. It creates the text files exactly as required but throws a run time error after it crosses certain number of rows, about 8000-9000. It works fine when I split the file into 4 files or so. How to make the script work with one file that has around 32000 rows. Please see the script below and suggest what changes I can do?

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateForEachLine()
Dim myPathTo As String
myPathTo = "C:\Users\9418\Desktop\Work Files\Vending"
Dim myFileSystemObject As Object
Set myFileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim fileOut As Object
Dim myFileName As String

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) Then
            myFileName = Cells(i, 1) & ".txt"
            Set fileOut = myFileSystemObject.OpenTextFile(myFileName, 8, True)
            fileOut.write Cells(i, 2) & "   " & Cells(i, 3) & "   " & Cells(i, 4) & "   " & Cells(i, 5) & vbNewLine
            fileOut.Close
        End If
    Next

Set myFileSystemObject = Nothing
Set fileOut = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: ... and what line is the error on?

Comment: Add an error handler to your script so you can continue with the next file, and increment your counter - I suspect it's some data that causing the issue. You could output these rows to list to check after the main program completes.  
https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/#A_Quick_Guide_to_Error_Handing

Comment: Hi Tim, the error is Run time error '13'. Type Mismatch

Comment: HI Jeeped, when I click on Debug, the error line shows on the line that says fileOut.write Cells(i,2)&"  "& Cells(i,3) & "  " and so on.

Comment: @user685590 you are right! there was some #N/A data that was causing issues. Once I deleted those specific rows then it worked!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Type mismatch error is suggesting that the datatype in the cells is not compatible or expected. I would imagine that this is because there is some incorrect 'data type' data in some of your rows, such as formula #N/A values or strings that exceed a certain length etc, that doesn't match with the memory declarations. Try searching through your data for blank rows, formula errors, or lengthy strings that may cause a type mismatch error and try the code again.